# Typo3 12: how to login FE user with php code

Tags: php, authentication, typo3-12.x

The frontend login has changed in TYPO3 12. I try to follow the new [documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/main/en-us/ApiOverview/Authentication/Index.html).

The authentication of the frontend user works fine, however after the redirect he is not logged in. What is missing in my php code which I have mostly copied from TYPO3 12 Core? What else must be done to log in the front end user automatically without a form view?

```
<?php

use Psr\Log\LoggerAwareInterface;
use Psr\Log\LoggerAwareTrait;

use TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\ContentObject\ContentObjectRenderer;
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Crypto\PasswordHashing\SaltedPasswordService;
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Context\UserAspect;
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Context\Context;
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Session\SessionManager;
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility;


class System implements LoggerAwareInterface
{
    use LoggerAwareTrait;

    /**
    * @var SessionBackendInterface
    */
    protected $sessionBackend;

    public $loginType = 'FE';
    
    public function login(
        ContentObjectRenderer $cObj,
        Localization $languageObj,
        Parameters $controlData,
        Url $url,
        $conf,
        $username,
        $cryptedPassword,
        $requiresAuthorization = true,
        $redirect = true
    ) {
        $result = true;
        $ok = true;
        $authenticated = false;
        $message = '';
        $authServiceObj = null;
        $request = $controlData->getRequest();
        $frontendUser = $controlData->getFrontendUser();
        $user = [];

        // Log the user in
        $loginData = [
            'uname' => $username,
            'uident' => $cryptedPassword,
            'uident_text' => $cryptedPassword,
            'status' => 'login',
        ];

        // Check against configured pid (defaulting to current page)
        $frontendUser->checkPid = true;
        $pageIds = ($cObj->data['pages'] ? $cObj->data['pages'] . ',' : '') . $controlData->getPid();
        $frontendUser->checkPid_value =
            SystemUtility::getRecursivePids(
                $pageIds,
                $cObj->data['recursive']
            );

        // Get authentication info array
        $authInfo = $frontendUser->getAuthInfoArray($request);

        if ($requiresAuthorization) {
            $ok = false;
            $serviceKeyArray = [];
            $serviceKeyArray[] = SaltedPasswordService::class;

            if (
                $conf['authServiceClass'] != '' &&
                $conf['authServiceClass'] != '{$plugin.tx_agency.authServiceClass}' &&
                class_exists($conf['authServiceClass'])
            ) {
                $serviceKeyArray = array_merge($serviceKeyArray, GeneralUtility::trimExplode(',', $conf['authServiceClass']));
            }

            $serviceChain = '';
            $ok = false;

            while (
                !$ok &&
                is_object(
                    $authServiceObj =
                        GeneralUtility::makeInstanceService(
                            'auth',
                            'authUserFE',
                            GeneralUtility::trimExplode(',', $serviceChain, true)
                        )
                )
            ) {
                $subType = 'authUserFE';
                $isProcessed = 
                    $authServiceObj->processLoginData($loginData, 'normal');
                if (!$isProcessed) {
                    continue;
                }
                $authServiceObj->initAuth($subType, $loginData, $authInfo, $frontendUser);
                
                // Get user info
                $user =
                    $authServiceObj->fetchUserRecord(
                        $loginData['uname']
                        // $authInfo['db_user'],
                    );

                if (
                    !empty($user) &&
                    ($ret = $authServiceObj->authUser($user)) > 0
                ) {
                    // If the service returns >=200 then no more checking is needed - useful for IP checking without password
                    if ((int)$ret >= 200) {
                        $ok = true;
                        $authenticated = true;
                    } else if ((int)$ret >= 100) {
                        // nothing
                    } else {
                        $ok = true;
                        $authenticated = true;
                    }
                } else {
                    $authenticated = false;
                    break;
                }

                if (!empty($user)) {
                    $serviceChain .= ',' . $authServiceObj->getServiceKey();
                }
            }
        } else {
            $ok = true;
        }

        if ($ok && $authenticated) {

            // Enforce session so we get a FE cookie. Otherwise autologin might not work :
            
            $frontendUser->storeSessionData();
            $frontendUser->setAndSaveSessionData('login', true);
            // Login successfull: create user session
            $sessionRecord = $frontendUser->createUserSession($user);

            if (isset($authInfo['userSession']['ses_data'])) {
                // Preserve session data on login
                $sessionData = $this->getSessionBackend()->update(
                    $frontendUser->id,
                    ['ses_data' => $authInfo['userSession']['ses_data']]
                );
                
                $frontendUser->user = array_merge(
                    $user,
                    $sessionData
                );
            } else {
                $frontendUser->user = $user;
            }

            // The login session is started.
            $frontendUser->loginSessionStarted = true;

            // $frontendUser->createUserAspect();
            // $aspect = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(UserAspect::class, $frontendUser);
            // $context = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(Context::class);
            // $context->setAspect('frontend.user', $aspect);
        } elseif (
            is_object($authServiceObj) &&
            in_array(get_class($authServiceObj), $serviceKeyArray)
        ) {
            if (empty($user)) {
                // No enabled user of the given name
                $message = sprintf($languageObj->getLabel('internal_no_enabled_user'), $loginData['uname']);
            } else {
                // auto login failed...
                $message = $languageObj->getLabel('internal_auto_login_failed');
            }
            $result = false;
        } else {
            // Required authentication service not available
            $message = $languageObj->getLabel('internal_required_authentication_service_not_available');
            $result = false;
        }

        // Delete regHash
        if (
            $controlData->getValidRegHash()
        ) {
            $regHash = $controlData->getRegHash();
            $controlData->deleteShortUrl($regHash);
        }

        if ($result == false) {
            if (strlen($message)) {
                $this->logger->critical($message);
            }
            $ok = false;
        }

        if (
            $ok &&
            $redirect
        ) {
            // Redirect to configured page, if any
            $redirectUrl = $controlData->readRedirectUrl();
            if (!$redirectUrl && $result == true) {
                $redirectUrl = trim($conf['autoLoginRedirect_url']);
            }

            if (!$redirectUrl) {
                if ($conf['loginPID']) {
                    $redirectUrl = $url->get($conf['loginPID'], '', [], ['regHash']);
                } else {
                    $redirectUrl = $controlData->getSiteUrl();
                }
            }

            header('Location: ' . GeneralUtility::locationHeaderUrl($redirectUrl));
        }

        return $result;
    }

    
    /**
    * Returns initialized session backend. Returns same session backend if called multiple times
    *
    * @return SessionBackendInterface
    */
    protected function getSessionBackend()
    {
        if (!isset($this->sessionBackend)) {
            $this->sessionBackend = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(SessionManager::class)->getSessionBackend($this->loginType);
        }
        return $this->sessionBackend;
    }
}
```

Comment: The method to use the class  `TYPO3\CMS\Core\Crypto\PasswordHashing\SaltedPasswordService` has been removed in TYPO3 11 already. The programmer must write an own Authentication Service class. See [Authentication](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/12.4/en-us/ApiOverview/Authentication/Index.html)

Comment: This code is not completely wrong. The login only seemed not to work, because the redirect went to the wrong page where a new user had to be created in any case. Improvements: Use a Context class by dependency injection and use `$context->getPropertyFromAspect('frontend.user', 'id');` to get the front end user id of a logged in user. And execute `$context->setAspect('frontend.user', $frontendUser->createUserAspect());`to set the current frontend user.